# Is there a way to train Doc2Vec on a corpus of docs and be able to take a novel doc and see how similar it is to the trained corpus?

Tags: nlp, semantic-similarity, doc2vec

I have a project idea, where I train a bunch of documents on Doc2Vec and then take a novel, input doc, and ideally be able to be told how similar it is to the docs supplied for training as a whole or how well it "fits" with the training docs. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible approaches:

- using simple similarity measures (e.g. cosine) to compare the new document against every training document.
- train a binary classifier to distinguish the reference documents from "anything else". Requires negative examples, it's usually difficult to have a representative sample.
- Use [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification), i.e. train a model using only the reference documents. The model tries to represent this class of documents and considers anything else as negative.
- Could even consider it as a regression problem, i.e. score documents by how similar they are from the reference documents.